# Updating local git repository with remote repository

Tags: git, github

I've been reading about `git pull` and `git fetch`, I'm getting a little confused now. So on the master branch, there have been commits made since I've last done work. If I want to update my local repository to continue working, am I supposed to pull the commits from the master branch to my own branch? I tried to do a `git fetch` from my own branch to update it. But from what I read, this doesn't completely update my local repository and that I would need to merge.

Comment: "master branches"? there's only one branch called master..

Comment: @ItayB: Well, there's (zero or) one `master` *per repository*. If you have a Git repository yourself, and you `git fetch` from another Git repository named `origin`, there are two `master`s: yours, and origin's. But it really does depend on what/how you count!

Comment: @torek agree - it depend how you count. I'm counting `master` and `origin/master` as different branches

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` only downloads patch files from a remote repository, but does not apply them. In simple terms `git pull` is a short-hand for `git fetch; git merge;`.
To update your files `git fetch` is not sufficient - make a `git pull`

Also, the question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you. To update my local repository, do I checkout the master branch and perform a `git pull origin master` or do this on my own branch?

Comment: @Jasmine: for beginners, I strongly recommend avoiding `git pull`, as it seems to be overly magic. Use `git fetch`, which directs your Git to call up the other Git at `origin` and download items, and then use `git merge` or `git rebase`—whichever your work-flow calls for—to *integrate* the items you just picked up. When something goes wrong (and eventually it will), you'll know which *part* went wrong and hence at least know what to ask next. It's also useful to know that `git fetch` is always safe no matter what state you are in, but `git merge` and `git rebase` need things to be "clean".

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is actually a combination of: `git  fetch` & `git merge`. You probably what to do the following:

1. `git checkout master` # switch to master branch on your local repo.
2. `git status` # make sure you are clean
3. `git pull` # get last commits from remote repo
4. `git checkout <your-branch>` # switch back to your side branch
5. `git merge master` # merge the master commits into your-branch
6. optionally: `git push origin <your-branch>` # to backup your commits/updates in remote repo

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` will download all the repository information from your `remote`. This stores it in the remote (try running `git remote show`). So now you will have a branch called `origin\master`. You can see your branches on your remote by running `git branch -a`
`origin\master` is different from `master` so you will need to `git merge origin\master` to syncronize with your remote origin.

`git pull` automatically runs several commands

- `git fetch`
- `git merge origin\master`

I would recommend going through this quick tutorial: https://try.github.io/